# About the omission cube of the Grease pencil in Blender v2.8

Tags: interface, grease-pencil

[image: There should be a small orange cube at the center pivot of the object and the object data supposed to appear on the right of the list]

[image]

Here are the differences between my viewport and the Tutorial's viewport.
Q. How to show the small orange cube and the object data?

Answer (score 0):

The 3 axes arrows has become the orange cube, and the pen icon has become the green squiggly line.

The icons have been changed since the tutorial was recorded in the early stages of the Version 2.80 and the icons were not final at the time. But you should find the same information in these submenus.

Although I think there has been changes to how the grease pencil object data works so you might see things arranged differently.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. How does the green squiggly line look like??

Comment: Most important is the object data still cannot be found that I am not able to edit the layer of the brush.....

Comment: There is only one green icon on your screenshot. It's located exactly at the same place as the pen icon in the screenshot from the tutorial

Comment: Found the object data finally. Thank you so much for helping!!